# Conjuctions for the list of criterias

Tags: java, hibernate

I have

```
List<Criteria> criterias;

//Getting the list
```

and I'd like to apply `or` operation to those criterias. I mean, I would not like to call `criteria.list()` for each criteria and then evaluating intersection of them, becase I think it's going be too expensive operation. Is there something in hibernate for such case?

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#disjunction%28org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion...%29

Comment: @JBNizet Well, I asked about Criteria, not Criterion. Criteria cannot be cast to Criterion... Therfore we cannot use `public static Conjunction conjunction(Criterion... conditions)`

Comment: Sure, but instead of adding all your restrictions to a Criteria, you can all add them to a Conjunction, which is a Criterion, and then create a Disjunction containing all the conjunctions.

Comment: @JBNizet Indeed, I got that, thank you.